# How to run PHP websocket on OVH cloud-web-1 host,

Tags: php, websocket, ovh

I have a PHP application which uses websockets,
When I run it on my local, it works fine, but when I deploy it on my web host, it doesn't anymore.
I am on cloud-web-1 of OVH.
I saw that this plan supports websockets.
When I launch the PHP server script with SSH, it works fine, but on the client side, when I create a js object socket with url of the websocket ws://ip-address:port or wss or ws://my-domain:port , it never work and it always show error on the browser console like "Connection to websoccket failed.",

Help me please,
Thanks

Comment: check that your websocket server is listening on the right adress, like IP-Adress:Port or my-domain:Port but not NOT on localhost:port

Comment: I already did this. But it always goes on failure.  I tried with the domain and then with the IP address

Comment: Please add some sample code of what you tried

Answer (score 0):

On the server side (your PHP code), ensure your websocket is listening on `http://0.0.0.0:<port>` (I tried with port `3000`).

On the HTML side, here is an example of connection to your websocket:

```html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var host = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
  var socket = io.connect(host);
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
     <your code>
  }
</script>
```